# How to create an .exe file with external .dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, itext, exe

I've tried almost everything found on the net to solve this problem, but it just seems to not work!
I created a .exe file from a visual studio 2013 project using wpf. I want this file to create pdfs, so I added as references .dlls concerning itextsharp.
Everything works fine if I keep my .exe file in the same directory as itextsharp's .dlls. But when I try to run the .exe outside, the program crashes.

I've tried to use ILMerge, I read it is pretty good to merge .exe and .dll, but when I double-click one the newly-created .exe file nothing happens.

The command I wrote in my command window, once in the ILMerge folder, was:

```
    ilmerge C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\PDFWriter.exe C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\itextsharp.dll /out:C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\merged.exe /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Normally you just put your DLLs in the same folder as the EXE. Why do you want to do something different than that?

Comment: To prevent the need of dragging tons of dll's around @JoeWhite

Comment: You have to run that ilmerge after every build. Did you do that? Also check the event log, and add exception handling in your app. It might point you to the problem.

Comment: I want to do this in order to have a unique .exe file and to be able to give it to my friends without the need to add the .dlls, too.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I just want to merge my final .exe file, in the command window that instruction seems to work fine, it does not  tell me about errors. The problem is when I try to run the new .exe file...nothing happens!

Comment: FWIW people are used to having lots of extra stuff alongside the actual exe file. It is very uncommon to distribute just an exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Fody.Cosura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) project for merging. A lot nice to work with than ILMerge.

All you need to do is to install nuget package in your project:

```
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

And you are pretty much done. You can adjust the [configuration](https://github.com/Fody/Costura#configuration-options), but that is not always required as just installing the package does the bulk for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine, you solved me a big problem :) thanks!